# Showing the previous item in a pivot control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-interface, pivot

Is it possible to set a pivot control to centre the current item title and have the next and previous items to either side on a pivot control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without rewriting the default template. What you're looking for is an implementation similar to the CoverFlow one. You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2009/05/13/coverflow-%E2%80%93-built-using-silverlight-3s-projection-feature/). As a source of inspiration, you can look at the source code for [CoverFlow for Silverlight](http://silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com/).